# .htaccess - обращение к файлам отличного формата

Tags: .htaccess

На хостинге находятся множество файлов со следующими именами:

> index.php.html
>   index.php_cat=1.html
>   index.php_product=1.html
>   index.php_view=content.html
>   pages.php_view=order.html
>   pages.php_view=register.html
>   price.php.html

Нужно сделать так, чтоб при обращении в браузере по линкам, тянулся контент с этих файлов. Линки в браузере соответственно:

> mydomain.com/index.php
>   mydomain.com/index.php?cat=1
>   mydomain.com/index.php?product=1
>   mydomain.com/index.php?view=content
>   mydomain.com/pages.php?view=order
>   mydomain.com/pages.php?view=register
>   mydomain.com/price.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Требуемую задачу выполняет следующая конструкция:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1_%{QUERY_STRING}.html? [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1.html [L,R=301,NC]
```

Если же требуется, чтобы адрес в строке браузера не менялся, нужно просто убрать директиву редиректа `R=...`, т.е. содержимое файла будет следующим:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1_%{QUERY_STRING}.html? [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: выбрасывает mydomain.com//var/www/u0135436/public_html/sekretlady.com/.php_cat=1.html

Comment: Замените `(\.php$)` на `^(.*\.php)$`

Comment: всё то же самое

Comment: Перед `$1` добавьте `/`. Если не поможет, то `$1` замените на `http://sekretlady.com/$1`

Comment: @valextt Извиняюсь. Что-то я такое неработающее нацарапал... :-( Поправил. Протестил на `xampp`. Теперь перенаправляет правильно. P.S. Влепите мне кто-нибудь минус за идиотизм...

Comment: Добавил последнее изменение, но сейчас выполняется редирект. Как сделать так, чтоб не было редиректа, а просто тянулся контент с этих файлов, а линк остался первоначально неизменным в браузере?

Comment: @valextt Обновил ответ.

Comment: Работает, супер, спасибо!